# Concatenating DataArray with tolerance in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I would like to concatenate several `DataArray` whose dimension coordinates are almost aligned, like this:

```py
import xarray as xr
da1 = xr.DataArray([[0, 1], [2, 3]], coords=[[0, 1], [0, 1]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da2 = xr.DataArray([[4, 5], [6, 7]], coords=[[0.1, 1.1], [-0.1, 0.9]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da = xr.concat([da1, da2], 'z')
```

But since the coordinates are not exactly aligned, I get for `da`:

```
<xarray.DataArray (z: 2, x: 4, y: 4)>
array([[[nan,  0., nan,  1.],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan,  2., nan,  3.],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [ 4., nan,  5., nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [ 6., nan,  7., nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 0.1 1.0 1.1
  * y        (y) float64 -0.1 0.0 0.9 1.0
Dimensions without coordinates: z
```

It would be nice to be able to tolerate some differences in the coordinates, as we can do with `reindex`:

```py
da = xr.concat([da1, da2], 'z', method='nearest', tolerance=0.2)
```

Is there a reason why this functionality doesn't exist? How can I work around it?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @jhamman, the following example illustrates better how I would like the output `DataArray` to be:

```py
import xarray as xr
da1 = xr.DataArray([[0, 1], [2, 3]], coords=[[0, 1], [0, 1]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da2 = xr.DataArray([[4, 5], [6, 7]], coords=[[1.1, 2.1], [1.1, 2.1]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da = xr.concat([da1, da2], 'z', method='nearest', tolerance=0.2) # doesn't exist yet
da
```

Note that coordinate 1.1 from `da2` has changed to 1 from `da1`, because it is close enough. Coordinate 2.1 from `da2` couldn't be matched with any coordinate in `da1`, so it was kept as-is. Matching coordinates thus depends on the order in which the `DataArray` are processed:

```
<xarray.DataArray (z: 2, x: 3, y: 3)>
array([[[ 0.,  1., nan],
        [ 2.,  3., nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan],
        [nan,  4.,  5.],
        [nan,  6.,  7.]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0 1 2.1
  * y        (y) float64 0 1 2.1
Dimensions without coordinates: z
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how the output dataset would look? What would the coordinates and dimensions be?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you'll need to manually reindex your arrays before calling `xr.concat`:

```
In [1]:     import xarray as xr
   ...:     da1 = xr.DataArray([[0, 1], [2, 3]], coords=[[0, 1], [0, 1]], dims=['x', 'y'])
   ...:     da2 = xr.DataArray([[4, 5], [6, 7]], coords=[[0.1, 1.1], [-0.1, 0.9]], dims=['x', 'y'])
   ...:     da2r = da2.reindex_like(da1, method='nearest', tolerance=0.2)
   ...:     da = xr.concat([da1, da2r], 'z')
   ...:     da
   ...:
Out[1]:
<xarray.DataArray (z: 2, x: 2, y: 2)>
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
  * y        (y) int64 0 1
Dimensions without coordinates: z
```

> Is there a reason why this functionality doesn't exist?

I don't think so. I suggest opening an issue on the xarray GitHub issue tracker to suggest this feature.

Comment: Thanks @jhamman. I thought about your solution, but we would also need to handle the range of the coordinates, right? It should be the "union" of both arrays, not the intersection.